# Differentiate messages within same status code from web api

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-403

I am developing a web API which will return `Forbidden` http status for multiple reasons-

- User is blocked.
- IP is blocked.
- Request limit exceeded.
- User is unverified.

I am returning response in following way-

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, message);    //message : "Limit reached" etc.
```

Now, I need to handle these reasons differently at client. Should I identify the reason from returned message? This message is to be displayed to user and might change in future.

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best practice for this?

Rather than trying to invent a schema of your own, you should probably look for something standardized, like [Problem Details for HTTP APIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807).

Problem Details describes a human readable "title" and "detail" field, and a "type" that is a link to human readable documentation.

> Consumers MUST use the "type" string as the primary identifier for the problem type; the "title" string is advisory and included only for users who are not aware of the semantics of the URI and do not have the ability to discover them (e.g., offline log analysis). Consumers SHOULD NOT automatically dereference the type URI.
>
> Consumers SHOULD NOT parse the "detail" member for information; [extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807#section-3.2) are more suitable and less error-prone ways to obtain such information.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message should be descriptive for your client. Ideally you need to include the following information:

1. developers message (technical description - "`cache is out-of-date`", "`service A is unavailable`")
2. human-readable message (business description - "`this time is booked already`", "`company A is closed and cannot be modified`")
3. hint how to solve ("`refresh your cache`", "`try again in 5 minutes`", "`request permission A from administrator`")
4. href to your online documentation
5. Header like "`error_code: 100`". A custom code should also be described in the documentation. This one you may rely on in your client's code and handle appropriately

Also what do you mean by:

> User is unverified.

In case user is not Authenticated (api doesn't know **who** is he), api is supposed to return `401` http status code. If user lacks some permission and therefore cannot modify the resource than `403` is totally fine. However it would be great to describe which permission exactly is missing